# Diagnostic puzzle - laptop randomly fails at OS startup

Tags: laptop, diagnostic, boot

I have a problem which has been bothering me for a year now and I would be grateful if somebody could help me. I will try to be as brief and concise as possible:

Laptop: [HP Probook 4525s](http://h18004.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/13838_na/13838_na.pdf), HDD 160GB, OS Windows 8, CPU: AMD Turion™ II X2 P520, Graphics: ATI Mobility Radeon HD 530v 512MB
Age: 4 years

The problem is that the laptop randomly fails to complete the OS startup. Description of behavior after I press the start button:

1. The laptop always seems to start normally - CPU, HDD, RAM, Display - all of them seems to work normally (CPU and RAM failure would be indicated by a some acoustic signal[internal beep], or the pc wouldn't start at all - I assume)
2. The "windows logo" appears (win8) along with the "loading indicator" - always! - important to note, that the laptop never fails till this point.
3. After the win logo appears, the laptop SOMETIMES (70% of the boots) kind of "freezes" in the state where only the HDD is working (and I guess the CPU and the Ram as well), the display is on, but there is nothing else (black background while the display is still on). From this point, the OS never finishes the start up. I've tried to wait even 10 hrs :).
4. From the "frozen" point, I have to hard-turn off the laptop (keep the power button pressed), since there is nothing else I can do.

After point 4 - multiple iterations of points 1-3 occur (in other words, I try to start the laptop multiple times, without success). Sometimes, the laptop finally starts up after trying 5 or 6 times.

Some interesting notes: This occurs even when I re-install the OS (win7, win8), or even with Linux! (tried distributions Mandriva and Ubuntu) - when Linux is installed, the OS seems to start normally, but the startup again, is never finished.

I would expect this to be some corrupted OS issue, since all the HW components seem to start normally, and the startup fails always in the same spot of the system boot. But apparently it is some HW problem since re-installing the OS doesn't help?

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: Can you enable [boot-logging](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows-8/windows-startup-settings-including-safe-mode) and check what the last thing it which gets printed during boot? (I both Linux  and windows freeze at the moment it is initializing the same hardware  then you have a strong hint where to look.